# Preserve original dates, Xarray Groupby

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm reducing an xarray dataset by day

```
new_dataset = dataset.groupby('time.day').first()
```

I'm expecting `time` dimension values similar to

```
array([ '2016-09-03T23:21:19.500000000', '2016-09-10T23:12:58.500000000', '2016-10-03T23:20:13.500000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

but am receiving integer values under a dimension called `days`

```
array([ 1,  2 ])
```

Preserving the dimension types of this grouped xarray is important in using it as a drop-in operation to pre-existing workflows. Furthermore plotting time series of a point sampled from this xarray along the days axis will not preserve the spacing that days originally had between one another in the time domain.

Is there a simple or xarrays way of mapping days to datetime64 objects? Or should I independently group time coordinates of the original dataset and re-map them separately?

Answer (score 1):

`dataset.groupby('time.day').first()` groups data by day of the month, i.e. (1 Jan 2016, 1 Feb 2016, 1 Mar 2016,...,1 Dec 2019) are all grouped together. The output will be an array of up to 31 elements. The `first` operation reduces these groups by taking the first member of the group.

I suspect this isn't what you want to do, and that you are trying get the first data point for each calendar day. In which case, use `dataset.resample(time='D').first()`.